# Verify text is different languages on a webpage using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium Webdriver.

I am automating a webpage that changes its language after choosing the corresponding language from a drop down available on top of the webpage.

I can get and verify the text present on webpage in **English** by making use of element.getText() method and then validate it using assertEqual.

How can I validate the text for a different language, say Japanese?

Comment: Using same way First getText then compare result with expected one.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest following way

For complex UI

1.Identify keywords in Japanese (OR other language for which have to test) on Expected Page.
2.Verify that Page is loaded successfully.
3.Use image comparison library to match with expected.
  JAVA image comparison library link http://b22222.com/files/imagecompare.zip

simple UI

1.Identify keywords in Japanese (OR other language for which have to test) on Expected Page.
2.Verify that Page is loaded successfully.
3.Compare  with expected word in corrsponding language Please use of element.getText() method and then validate it using assertEqual.

Please let me know your feedback for same.

Comment: Your image comparison library link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Different languages like Japanese, portugues, chinese traditional and simplified and others have different encoding for that reason you have change them to a standard. Let's say ASCII and supose that the element that you want to verify is the page title so:

```
    byte[] array1 = expectedTitle.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    byte[] array2 = driver.getTitle().getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Now you have both in a standard format and you can apply your assert:

```
    Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(array1, array2));
```

This works for all languages.